# Comparative function between values with sql

Tags: sql

I'm not very versed in sql but have a project i'm working on. Basically the goal is to in one operation take the completed value - scrap value and have it equal the completed value on the next operation line to see if they add up. If they add then do nothing but if they aren't equal to post an error. Then I need to loop through and do this for each line to compare each one.
[image: IMG1]

```
SELECT FROM 'dbo.Job_Operation'
WHERE ' dbo.Job_Operation.Run_Qty AS'  in ( dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey,  dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey+1)
IF ( (dbo.Job_Operation.Run_Qty in dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey - dbo.Job_Operation.Act_Scrap_Qty AS in dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey) != 
(dbo.Job_Operation.Run_Qty AS in dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey+1), 'A-Okay', 'ERROR')



DECLARE @i int = 0

WHILE @i <= dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i + 1
    SELECT FROM 'dbo.Job_Operation'
WHERE 'dbo.Job_Operation.Run_Qty AS'  in (dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey, dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey+1)
IF ( (dbo.Job_Operation.Run_Qty in dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey - scrap qty in dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey) != 
(dbo.Job_Operation.Run_Qty AS in dbo.Job_Operation.Job_OperationKey+1), 'A-Okay', 'ERROR')
END
```

Here's what i've tried to throw together but I don't think i'm close. Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Comment: is the data in the job_operation table in a particular order? if so you might want to look into the ROW_NUMBER functionality: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: ROW_NUMBER will allow you to create an itterable that would allow a self join to reference a previous row's values

Comment: @NathanTregillus I wonder how ROW_NUMBER() would help here? What's your solution?

Comment: ah, I like your answer with LEAD

Answer (score 1):

Use [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql) window function:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (OperationKey int, CompletedQty int, ScrapQty int);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(1040, 360, 8),
(1040, 360, 10),
(1040, 360, 0),
(1040, 360, 0);

SELECT *, CASE WHEN (CompletedQty - ScrapQty) != x.nextCompQty THEN 'ERROR' ELSE NULL END
FROM
(
    SELECT *, LEAD(CompletedQty) OVER(ORDER BY OperationKey) nextCompQty
    FROM @t
) x;
```

Comment: Hey @JohnyL this looks awesome. I was going to use row number to self join a CTE where the ailas column = the previous row's value. This is way cleaner

Comment: @NathanTregillus I encourage you to learn [window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) - they're just great!

Comment: so is there a way to have it dynamically grab the values without manually adding them?

Comment: @Trent Beg your pardon - what do you mean?

Comment: @johnyL In this here you're inserting the values into a table manually from what I see. I'm curious if there is a way to have it pull those values without having to manually input them and select the values from there. Some type of loop maybe? I'm very new to this and slightly confused. I don't work on projects like this very often at all and this is an oddball. So i'm trying to learn as much as I can and make it as efficient as possible.

Comment: @Trent The column with error is ***in no way*** added to the table - it lives only in duration of SELECT statement. Let me know if this is what you need.